# Transferring msv.value within the body of a function in solidity

Tags: solidity

If I have a `payable` function in Solidity, can I transfer `msg.value` directly to another address without having funds in the contract. For example:

```
function foo() payable {
  myaddr.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

If the contract has not received any funds yet, will this work? Or will it only work if there are at least `msg.value` worth of funds from a previous transaction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If the contract has not received any funds yet, will this work?*

Yes. This snippet works as a "transaction proxy", transferring the currently received value to `myaddr` without having to have the balance before the transaction.

Example:

1. Your contract has 0 ETH balance.
2. Execute `foo()` sending along 10 ETH
3. `myaddr` receives the 10 ETH, while your contract keeps the 0 balance

User executing the `foo()` function pays gas fees for both the main transaction (to your contract implementing `foo()`) and the internal transaction (from your contract to the `myaddr`).